Using Electron, can I find out the extension of a local file when the user clicks on it?
I am creating a desktop application using Electron, React, and TypeScript. My application is running in the background, and when the user clicks on an image file or any file, I want to know the extension of that file. Is this possible? If possible, please let me know if there is any way.
The method I looked for was electron app.on("open-file"), but I'm not sure if this can definitely solve my problem, and I'm not sure how to use it.

If by "when clicking on a file" you mean "when opening a file in my Electron application", you'll need to register your application as a handler for a file type and then listen for the "open-file" event.
Registering the application as a potential handler for certain file types is something you define when packaging your application for release, e.g. by using fileAssociations in Electron Builder but in the end it'll depend on the system and your users if they want to use your application as the default handler for the file types you plan to support.
To actually respond to the event, the documentation of the "open-file" event from app says that the callback to the listener will be supplied with the event object and the path (as a string) to the file that's being opened:
app.on("open-file", (event, path: string) => { console.log(path); }); 

As to how to get the extension from the path, that depends on how correct you want and need to be:

If you know that you'll always get a file with an extension, you can just split the string with "." and get the last segment.
If you know that you'll always get a file, you can split the string with "/" and get the last segment to find the file name and then split that as above.
If you don't know what your users will try to input as a thing to open (files with or without extensions or paths to directories), it's probably best to create a path object from the string and query the extension that way

